# Arithmetic problem with for loop in MATLAB guide

Tags: matlab, for-loop, popup, matlab-guide

i am new with MATLAB. 
I would like to use this formula in for loop: ℓ=taper1*ℓ−1
There is no error message but i can't see a proper value on output. (i control my values with calculator programs) (i checked my variables. and confirmed that they are true before this loop).
And my second problem is i don't know how to add new line with every increment. 
Here is my try:

```
l= (1:N); //creating and empty array
l(1)=((3*(10^8))/(2*f1)); //formula 
for i = 2:N
    l(i) = taper1 * l(i - 1);
    set(handles.popupmenu3,'String',l(i) );
end
```

i tried to add new line with this but didn't work

```
set(handles.popupmenu3,'String',l(i) \n );
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to `set` a numerical value to a `String`.

Use: `num2str(l(i))` for converting `l(i)` to `String`.

For adding new line, use can use `sprintf` as follows:

```
set(handles.popupmenu3, 'String', sprintf('%f\n', l(i)));
```

The following code seem to work for me:

```
N = 3;
f1 = 1;
taper1 = 0.5;

l = (1:N); %creating and empty array
l(1)=((3*(10^8))/(2*f1)); %formula 
for i = 2:N
    l(i) = taper1 * l(i - 1);
    %set(handles.popupmenu3, 'String', num2str(l(i)));
    set(handles.popupmenu3, 'String', sprintf('%f\n', l(i)));
end
```

It could be helpful if you add the values of all the elements to the question.

---

If you want to get a list of result, add the string values to a `cell array`:
Adding an end of line `\n` is not the way to do it.
Each row in the `popupmenu` is a member in a `cell array`.

For example:
`S{1} = 'aaa';`
`S{2} = 'bbb';`
`S{3} = 'ccc';`
`set(handles.popupmenu3, 'String', S);`

Check if the following code works:

```
N = 3;
f1 = 1;
taper1 = 0.5;

l = (1:N); %creating and empty array
l(1)=((3*(10^8))/(2*f1)); %formula 
for i = 2:N
    l(i) = taper1 * l(i - 1);
    %set(handles.popupmenu3, 'String', num2str(l(i)));

    str = get(handles.popupmenu3, 'String'); %Get older value of popupmenu3
    str{end+1} = num2str(l(i)); %Add new string to popupmenu list
    set(handles.popupmenu3, 'String', str); %Update popupmenu3
end
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aOQ1f.png)